# Inserting list of months between two dates into a table

Tags: sql-server

Hey i am looking to inset a list  month between two dates in to a second table  have it entering one of the months (with the Select Top 1) But im not sure how to get it to insert the full list

here is my Code below.

```
    DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME,
        @MonthList as Varchar(50)

SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';

SEt @MonthList = (SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate))  FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x WHERE   x.type = 'P'    AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate))
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS Month
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);

Insert Into Payments_ExpectedPayments(Month)
Values(@MonthList)
```

Comment: You should rethink your design. Keeping delimited strings is the wrong thing to do in 99.999% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME,


SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';


Insert Into Payments_ExpectedPayments(Month)
SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS Month
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need @monthlist variable

```
 DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME
SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';

INSERT INTO Payments_ExpectedPayments([Month])

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS [Month]
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);
```